# Can't add records to MySQL if the record contains an apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATED VERSION

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "metadata");
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
// Check connection
if($link === false){
  die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// my form located in index.php posts the data here.

$add_movie_original_name = $_POST['movie_original_name'];
$add_movie_tr_name = $_POST['movie_tr_name'];
$add_movie_year = $_POST['movie_year'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO movie(movie_original_name,movie_tr_name,movie_year) VALUES('$add_movie_original_name','$add_movie_tr_name','$add_movie_year')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I can't add records if there is an **apostrophe** in it. For instance, **Uncle Sam's** can't be added.

Here is the error I get. I tried to add a movie named **Movie's Name**.

ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO movie(movie_original_name,movie_tr_name,movie_year) VALUES('Movie's Name','','2014'). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Name','','2014')' at line 1

(I deleted my comments, so line number will be different)

I think I should use a trick to escape the characters, but couldn't find out how.

Comment: Use PDO. Prepare the statement.

Comment: It's a parse not runtime error. So what is the **real** code for lines 41-43?

Comment: @Jonast92: even though your point is valid - the OP has parse error

Comment: @zerkms True. OP, is the statement before `$add_record = $_POST['record'];` properly ended with a semicolon (`;`)? What does the line look like?

Comment: The `connect.php` file doesn't really matter much here, the lines above previously mentioned code in `insert.php` matter.

Comment: @zerkms, 41. and 43. lines are being used for commenting. The line 42 is starting with $sql = , it's the same line as I stated in the question.

Comment: First, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. second you should be able to use prepare statement.

Comment: Jonast92, yes it does. I am able to add records if I don't use a tilde in my record, so my code works. I am editing my question right now.

Comment: @Tamer: it's impossible that your code sometimes throws parse error, and sometimes does not.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Tamer The line that's not a comment then..

Comment: I updated the question details. Btw, thanks for the SQL Injection warning. This is a code block I use to learn the basics, will get to the security part soon, I hope.

Comment: And now you need to start using mysqli prepared statements

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() works but is deprecated, now I need to start using mysqli statements, as @zerkms says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nee to be preparing your statements so that you aren't vulnerable to an [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. To do this, you should be using [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Your current code would look like this as a prepared statement

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "metadata");
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO movie(movie_original_name,movie_tr_name,movie_year) VALUES('?','?','?')");
$statement->bind_param('sss', $add_movie_original_name, $add_movie_tr_name, add_movie_year);
$statement->execute();
```

Notice how in the actual SQL, I've replaced your variables with ?'s, this let's them be bound later on. In my bind_param method, the first parameter is how many variables you're binding, and what data types they are. There's one character for each variable, and they're all strings, so that character is "s". If you wanted to bind integers and strings, you would use

```
$statement->bind_param('sis', $string1, $int1, $string2);
```

Notice how the order of "sis" matches the order of what's passed it, string then integer then string again. According to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), there are four different types you can pass in, each with their own characters

- s for string
- i for integer
- d for double
- b for blob

So that's a short explanation of bound params. The problem you're having comes from the fact that your variables aren't escaped or bound, leaving them open to injection. This will fix your problem and make your code a little bit more secure.

Note: As pointed out by @bcintegrity, this isn't the be all end all for security. You're going to want to look into using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when echoing out your data that's been entered in by users in order to stop [XSS (Cross Site Scripts)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/) which can be very dangerous to not patch up.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a priority to use prepared statements. Prepared statements simply send the query separate from the values, so the db knows the values are not to be run as code. Prepared statements escape the values automatically :)

Here is an example:

```
$sqli = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","metadata");
if (!$sqli) {die("Can not connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error());}

$result = "INSERT INTO `movie`(movie_original_name,movie_tr_name,movie_year) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sqli, $result);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$_POST['movie_original_name'],$_POST['movie_tr_name'],$_POST['movie_year']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Be sure to use htmlspecialchars() if echoing values onto the page to protect from XSS:

```
$original_name_onscreen = htmlspecialchars($_POST['movie_original_name']);
$tr_name_onscreen = htmlspecialchars($_POST['movie_tr_name']);
$year_onscreen = htmlspecialchars($_POST['movie_year']);
```

**Note:** @Gareth Parker's example is object oriented style, similar to PDO, while mine is procedural style, similar to MySQL. Both are acceptable.

Comment: This one solved my problem, thank you. But now I am having issues with Turkish characters due to htmlspecialchars. How can I solve it?

I am also looking @Gareth's solution, too.

Comment: Happy to help! I was having the same problem. I was avoiding using prepared statements because I thought it would be difficult to learn, but I was wrong. Google search is helpful to find  a bunch of "how to's" on the subject. Have fun! Please be sure to accept an answer :)

Comment: Try using htmlentities() instead of htmlspecialchars(). To be clear, this is only needed for values that are echoed onto the page, not the parameters (values in the query).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. At least I found a more secure way to connect to db and solved my issue.
I don't want to take your time, I'll edit my question if I find a solution about Turkish characters. I need to check my phpmyadmin.